# is there any strings.xml like file in windows phone 8?

Tags: android, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've just started Windows phone 8 development with previous experience of Android Development.

I was just searching if there is any strings.xml like file in windows phone 8 where we can keep strings and **specially color codes**.  Yes i want to keep my own color codes in windows phone 8 project so that i may refer these colors in my Pages XML and in code.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special color codes can be placed in your App.xaml file in the resources part.

Use like the following:

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorWhite"
                     Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackGroundBrush"
                ImageSource="SplashScreenImage.jpg" />
    <Style x:Key="MyPageStyle"
           TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
        <Setter Property="Background">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Background_WindowsPhone.png"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill" />
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Application.Resources>
```

In your page you might then use the following:

```
<phone:ApplicationPage Style="{StaticResource MyPageStyle">
  <Grid Background="{StaticResource BackGroundBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Hi"
               Foreground="{StaticResource ColorWhite}" />
  </Grid>
</phone:ApplicationPage>
```